# Linha de tabela com link

Tags: html

Como faço para ter links em cada linha da minha tabela, por exemplo, quero que fique similar aos emails do Gmail, Hotmail etc., que tem várias linhas e quando você clica em alguma específica, abre o email completo referente. Tentei assim, mas não deu certo:

```html
<table class="table table-hover table-dark">
  <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>Marca</th>
     <th>Modelo</th>     
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr href="detalhe1.php">
      <td>Fitch</td>
      <td>4561A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr href="detalhe2.php">
      <td>Abercrombie</td>
      <td>CV591A</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Dá pra fazer com HTML puro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O atributo `href` é aplicável somente a algumas tags (`a`, `area`, `base`, `link`), portanto não possui efeito na tag `tr`.

> Dá pra fazer com HTML puro?

O que você pode fazer é usar o atributo `onclick` e redirecionar com `location.href` para a página desejada, mas não é HTML puro, porque o valor do atributo `onclick` já envolve um código JavaScript (no caso, o `location.href`).

Você pode, inclusive usar um CSS para alterar o cursor, de modo que a linha da tabela se comporte como uma área clicável:

```css
table.table tr{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-hover table-dark">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Marca</th>
<th>Modelo</th>     
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr onclick="location.href='detalhe1.php'">
<td>Fitch</td>
<td>4561A</td>
</tr>
<tr onclick="location.href='detalhe2.php'">
<td>Abercrombie</td>
<td>CV591A</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```